# TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not cv2.VideoCapture ,detect using neural network using mtcnn?

Tags: python, pytorch, face-detection, face-recognition

i've tried to detect faces from my webcam , but it was only detect the first face which appeared in the first frame , then it will crush , i have used mtcnn to detection operation

```
import cv2  
i = 0
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
while(True):      
    ret, frame = capture.read()

    frames_tracked = []
    print('\rTracking frame: {}'.format(i + 1), end='')
    frame_pil = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    frame_pil = Image.fromarray(frame_pil)
    boxes,_ = mtcnn.detect(frame_pil)
    frame_draw = frame_pil.copy()
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(frame_draw)     
    for box in boxes:
        draw.rectangle(box.tolist(), outline=(255, 0, 0), width=6)          

        frames_tracked.append(frame_draw.resize((640, 360), Image.BILINEAR))      
    d = display.display(frames_tracked[0], display_id=True)
    i = 1     
    try:        
        while True:
            d.update(frames_tracked[i % len(frames_tracked)]) 
            i += 1     
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

if cv2.waitKey('q') == 27:     
   break  

capture.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

while there is no face in the first frame it will crush , and rise the error

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

i want to even there is no faces it will remain capturing and looking for faces .
after detecting the first face in the first frame raised this error :

> TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not cv2.VideoCapture
>
> http://dpaste.com/04WXP33

thanks for helping

Comment: A line which throws this would help, but I assume it's the `for box in boxes:` one. You could verify that what you get back from `mtcnn.detect` is of an iterable type. If it's not - follow a different logic path.

Comment: can you explain it more please , how can i solve it ?

Comment: just add `if boxes` before `for box in boxes`

Comment: @Liam when there is no face it will raise (IndexError: list index out of range
) error and if there was a face it raised (ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
) !

Comment: i want to something like (cv2.imshow('video' , frame) ) is there something like that ?

Comment: @favoretti please let me know if there is a solution

Comment: before the line `boxes,_ = mtcnn.detect(frame_pil)` just add `boxes = []` so that there is an iterable instead of None when nothing is detected. For the other error, I am not familiar with cv2 but look at the docs and figure out how to get a byte stream from a VideoCapture object.

Comment: @ekmcd doesnt work